# Inserting a value into a Set using stateful lenses

Tags: haskell, state, haskell-lens

In yet another attempt to teach myself ekmett's lens library, I'm modifying a simple text-based hangman game to use lenses instead of record updates.  The code itself works, but I've come across a place where I feel like I'm using the lens library incorrectly.  This code works correctly, but it just doesn't look as elegant to me as all the lens tutorials I've seen.

First, my types:

```hs
data GameState = GameState
    { _guess :: Set Char
    , _secret :: String
    , _wrongGuesses :: Int
    } deriving (Eq, Show)

makeLenses ''GameState

type Game a = StateT GameState IO a
```

The function I'm bothered by is where I process the guess obtained from the user:

```hs
nextGuess :: Game ()
nextGuess = do
    gs <- get  -- GameState
    g <- getUserGuess :: Game Char
    -- If the user guessed a letter that wasn't in the secret word
    when (g `notElem` gs^.secret) $
        -- increment the number of wrong guesses
        wrongGuesses += 1
    -- Insert that guess into the set of guesses
    guess .= gs^.guess.to (insert g)
```

I'm mostly fine with the line

```hs
when (g `notElem` gs^.secret) $ wrongGuesses += 1
```

But the next line, where the guess is inserted into the current set of guesses seems like a roundabout way to do it.  Having to get the current set, insert, then set it again just doesn't sound like the "lens way of doing things", especially when the line before all I have to do to increment the `wrongGuesses` counter is use `+= 1`.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I'm much mistaken,

```
guess %= insert g
```

[`(%=)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-3.9.0.2/docs/Control-Lens-Setter.html#g:5) acts as modify and will feed the `Set` into `insert g` and then stick it back into `guess`.

Comment: That'd be it, I figured there would be an operator that I just hadn't tried yet.

Comment: @bheklilr I've always found a random binary search across the lens docs a reasonable way to find the correct operator. My assumption that there's always a combination of <5 operators hasn't been wrong yet ;)

Comment: I've just got to get used to the conventions for all the different operators.  I know they're pretty consistent, it just takes a while to learn.